# Is it possibly to make overlays appear beneath the map controls?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a map with a series of overlays constructed from external data displaying information.  I was wondering though is there is a way to set an overlay so it wont draw on top of the map controls?

By default they cover and hide the controls when in the location happens to overlap. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that by default overlays will appear as expected underneath controls.

What was going on in my case was the div that contained the overlay data had received a z-index style which was forcing it higher than the controls.

Answer (score -1):

It has to do with the way controls are added to your map.
Zoom in and out buttons is the default `ol.control.Zoom` and so it is the first control added on map. Then your custom control is added afterwards and so is overlapping the zoom control.

To overcome it, disable the default zoom control during map init like so:

```
......new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
     zoom:false//here is the disable
    ........
```

Then add your custom control and then, on top if it , add the zoom control.
All together should be :

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
     zoom:false
  }).extend([
    new app.CustomControl(),
    new ol.control.Zoom()
  ]),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
    rotation: 1
  })
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdhbnjLq/) to see it in action

**UPDATE**

To deal with Overlays, during overlay init set `insertFirst:true` so the overlay is displayed below the controls. Check the api doc [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html)

Comment: I'm not talking about a control I'm talking about an overlay.  As it is I'm beginning to suspect the problem is the content over the overlays forcing themselves on top rather than an inherent overlay issue.

Comment: then during overlay init set `insertFirst:true` so the overlay is displayed below the controls.Check the api doc -->http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html